# Hiding body in teaser display

Tags: 6, entities, nodes

For CCK fields you can set the display to be hidden for teaser display and shown when in full node display. How can I do the same for a node's body field as it's not listed on the display settings page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a module that would provide a user interface you could use to achieve what you're after. It is quite simple, however, to put together a tiny module and implement [hook_nodeapi('view')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) to remove the `body` part from the node content before it is built for display.

The most basic example would be the following, removing the body part from all nodes' teasers:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  if ($op == 'view' && $a3 /* teaser */) {
    unset($node->content['body']);
  }
}
```

Just pop a function like this into your module and adjust the `if` condition as needed.